# Backspace key doesn't work in FakeVim insert mode

Tags: qt-creator, qt5, fakevim

On Windows, I enabled FakeVim mode in QtCreator.  I found that pretty much everything I need works fine *except* the Backspace key.  While in insert mode, hitting backspace key does nothing.  I have attempted various `:set backspace` commands to fix this but to no avail. Does anyone have a solution to this problem?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Consider submitting a [bug report](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG/component/19488).

You can try unmapping backspace key with `:iunmap <BS>`. If that doesn't work, test if backspace key is really caught by FakeVim with `:inoremap <BS> <ESC>:Backspace works!` and pressing backspace in insert mode.

Other things to try:

- Toggle "Pass keys in insert mode" (`:set pk`, `:set nopk`).
- Disable reading `_vimrc` in options and restart Qt Creator.
- Re-map backspace in insert mode using `:inoremap <BS> <LEFT><DELETE>`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Interestingly enough, I discovered that the backspace key worked when I used the laptop keyboard, rather than my external keyboard.  But then, after I went back to my external keyboard, it started working...